# I can not run a server on Django

Tags: python, django

I have a problem: after the `python manage.py runserver` command I receive the following error which I can not solve:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0xb6712e64>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 107, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 252, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 22, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 24, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 74, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redactor/admin.py", line 3, in <module>
    from redactor.widgets import JQueryEditor
ImportError: cannot import name JQueryEditor
```

How can I solve this problem? Many where we recommend that you `sudo easy_install pip` the team, but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the name of the widget class is correct?
I was checking django-redactor and django-redactoreditor and they don't have a class named "JQueryEditor".

Comment: I changed the laptop re-installed the system and gradually restore it. By creating a clone of this project, which is on an old laptop running unconditionally, I look at the error and install the missing items.